# как оставить checkbox включенным после закрытия InfoWindow Googlemap

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api

Для фильтрации маркеров я использовал чекбоксы в инфо окнах. Все работает, но проблема в том, что после того, как я закрываю инфо окно, то чекбокс пропадает https://jsfiddle.net/pg3b62x4/2/

```
locations = [

['Объект 1<br/><a href="#">Читать далее</a><br/>Добавить к маршруту <input type="checkbox" name="way_points[]" class="way_points" value="54.332541126514506, 23.445510864257812">', 54.332541126514506, 23.445510864257812, 'туризм'],
['Объект 2<br/><a href="#">Читать далее</a><br/>Добавить к маршруту <input type="checkbox" name="way_points[]" class="way_points" value="54.332541126514506, 23.445510864257812">', 54.332541126514506, 23.445510864257812, 'замки'],

        ];
```

Comment: Насколько я понимаю ты же будешь использовать эти чекбоксы в дальнейшем . Как вариант на клик чекбокса добавить обработчик который добавляет информацию о состоянии чекбокса в localstorage. в свою очередь при клике на маркер смотреть в localstorage и проставлять атрибут checked, если это нужно

Comment: Спасибо большое, localstorage действительно должно мне помочь. Но почему то не реагирует на чекбокс который находится в ифоокне гугл мапс. Все остальные чекбоксы запоминаются, а в мапсе нет :( http://jsfiddle.net/4mtyu/4289/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы нигде не сохраняете состояние чекбокса. Для этого надо иметь массив значений и обработчик события по клику, изменяющий это значение. Вот обновлённая версия:

```js
/*
 * declare map and markers as a global variables
 */
var map;
// do not duplicate the same values
var markers = [{
    options: {
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(33.808678, -117.918921),
      map: map,
      icon: "http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_GZzKwf6g1o8/S6xwK6CSghI/AAAAAAAAA98/_iA3r4Ehclk/s1600/marker-green.png"
    },
    checked: true,
    markerObject: null,
  },
  {
    options: {
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(33.818038, -117.928492),
      map: map
    },
    checked: false,
    markerObject: null,
  },
  {
    options: {
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(33.803333, -117.915278),
      map: map
    },
    checked: false,
    markerObject: null,
  }
];

function generateHTML(id, value, checked) {
  return `Добавить к маршруту <input type="checkbox" name="way_points[]" class="way_points" value="${value}"" ${checked ? "checked" : ""} id=${id}>`
}

/*
 * use google maps api built-in mechanism to attach dom events
 */
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", function() {

  /*
   * create map
   */
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_div"), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(33.808678, -117.918921),
    zoom: 14,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

  /*
   * create infowindow (which will be used by markers)
   */
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  /*
   * marker creater function (acts as a closure for html parameter)
   */
  function createMarker(options, index) {
    const marker = new google.maps.Marker(options);
    const m = markers[index];
    if (m) {
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
        const html = generateHTML('checkbox_' + index, m.value, m.checked);
        infoWindow.setContent(html);
        infoWindow.open(options.map, this);
        var checkbox = document.querySelector('#checkbox_' + index);
        if (checkbox) {
          checkbox.addEventListener('change', function() {
            m.checked = !m.checked;
            console.log('m', m);
          })
        }
      });
    }
    return marker;
  }

  /*
   * add markers to map
   */
  for (let i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    const marker = markers[i];
    marker.options.map = map;
    marker.value = `${marker.options.position.lat()},${ marker.options.position.lng()}`;
    console.log(marker);
    markers[i].markerObject = createMarker(markers[i].options, i);
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font: 12px sans-serif;
}

h1,
p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&amp;sensor=false"></script>
<div id="map_div" style="height: 400px;"></div>
```

Обратите внимание, что код HTML чекбокса генерируется после клика на маркере каждый раз, иначе (если это сделать в самом начале) у вас так и будет каждый раз одно состояние чекбокса.
Пример можно дописать с учётом использования localStorage.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/globadaniil/4mtyu/4291/)

Comment: Спасибо большое, прошу прощения, но не могли бы помочь еще с моим кодом. Так как слишком много копировать то он не работает в jsfiddle я скопировал базовый пример, но по нему не получается понять как сделать так же с моим. Вот именно мой вариант отображения чекбоксов и инфоокон. https://jsfiddle.net/pg3b62x4/2/

Comment: Не очень понятно, с чем нужно помочь. Если я ответил я на этот  вопрос верно, отметьте ответ как правильный. Насчёт другой задачи лучше создайте новый вопрос.

Comment: Вопрос тот же. Только у меня не получается внедрить ваш код в свой (тот что в последнем комментарии), что бы не пропадали чекбоксы.

Comment: Так вы в вопросе привели пример не своего кода? Просто здесь *https://jsfiddle.net/pg3b62x4/2/* явно всё отличается. Вам нужно было изначально свой код и показывать.

Comment: да. просто мой код не запускался в fiddle потому скопировал базовый, думал на его примере если подскажут пойму.